# Samsung Tab S: Camera don't work in apps (although it works perfectly on camera app)

Tags: samsung, camera

I can take pictures with my tablet using camera built-in app from Android. My problem is when i use apps like Facebook Messenger / Snapchat / Skype / Hangouts ... the photograph is wrong scaled (stretched). It only occurs on apps. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing the cache for the afftected apps. Just go to settings> apps> click the affected app the press the "clear cache" button.